# How do I train a multiple-speaker model (speech synthesis) based on Tacotron 2 and espnet?

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, audio-processing, speech-recognition, speech-synthesis

I'm new to Speech Synthesis & Deep Learning. Recently, I got a task as described below:

I have problem in training a multi-speaker model which should be created by **[Tacotron2](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2)**. And I was told I can get some ideas from **[espnet](https://github.com/espnet/espnet)**, which is a end-to-end audio tools library. In this way, I found a good dataset called **libritts:** http://www.openslr.org/60/. And it's also found at **espnet**: https://github.com/espnet/espnet#tts-results
[image]

---

### Here is my initial thought：

1. Download libritts corpus / Read the **espnet** code: *../espnet/egs/libritts/tts1/run.sh*, learning how to train the libritts corpus by pytorch-backend.

> **Difficulty:** But I cannot get it across that how the author trained a libritts.tacotron2.v1 as I didn't found anything about tacotron2 along those shells related to run.sh. Maybe He didn't make those codes open-source.

2. Read the tacotron2 code and tune it into a multi-speaker network:

> **Difficulty:** I found the code is really complex.... I just got lost in reading these codes, without a clear understanding about how to tune this model. Cause Tacotron2 was designed with a LJSpeech Dataset(only 1 person).

3. Training the multi-speaker model with tiny set of dataset (http://www.openslr.org/60/) to save time.

[image]

> they contains about 110 people's data, which can be enough for my scenario.

### In the end:

Coud you please help me about my questions. I've been puzzled by this problem for a long time...